# select distinct coredata ios

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to `select distinct` results such that the `lastobject` found but `distinct` with no repetitions !!!

I'm using `CoreData` in `iOS`and want to use a predicate to select distinct results. My SQL query is like:

```
select distinct * from table
```

**My Function to fetch:**

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getResults :(NSString *)entity
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entity];

//    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
//    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

    NSMutableArray *result = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    return result;
}
```

How can I get the `lastobject` and `distinct` results from the result.

Comment: Have you tried using a predicate with your fetch request? Give it a search, and see if it helps..

Comment: What do you mean by "lastobject"?

Comment: This question is very confusing.  I can't figure out what you are asking.